# Javascript not loading mysql data phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cordova

I have a website written in HTML/Javascript and I use jquery to load data from MYSQL by calling php files. The website is working. I am trying to phonegap the same website but the data from MySQL is not loading. I am not using localhost in the database connect. Is there something wrong with my jquery?

```
<!-- Ajax for JSON -->
<script src="dist/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="featured_items" class="streamline message-box message-nicescroll-bar">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready(function () {
          /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
          $.getJSON('php/items.php', function (get_items) {
          /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
          $.each(get_items, function (get_items_key, get_items_val) {
             $("#featured_items").append(
                '//HTML Code Here'
             );
          });
       });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Your address is wrong, you need a complete URL to your server like https://www.example.com/php/items.php

Comment: example.com without the http did not work and even broke the working website. example.com/php/items.php with the http did work on the website but did not solve the data not loading in phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get data like this

```
var table_data = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
    type: "post",
url: SITE_URL,
dataType: "json",
    async: false
}).responseText);
```

then run following code

```
$.each(table_data, function(index, item) { })
```

Hope it is work for you

Comment: I used that and tested in the website and now that is blank. Maybe it is my Json Encode in the php file?

Comment: Please verify that you have written proper url in `SITE_URL` variable and into your php file,after getting output you have written `echo json_encode($result);`